# Launching JNLP without using the JnlpDownloadServlet class

Tags: java, .net, servlets, jnlp

Oracle recommends using the `JnlpDownloadServlet` [sample](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/downloadservletguide.html) to launch JNLP from a web application.

For whatever reasons, I am unable to use it and have to code my own JNLP launch.

This is what I have come up with (Servlet which launches it):

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
    throws ServletException, IOException 
{
    performTask(request, response);
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
    throws ServletException, IOException 
{
    performTask(request, response);
}

private void performTask(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
     throws ServletException, IOException 
{
    response.setContentType("application/x-java-jnlp-file");
    byte [] b = getJNLP(..some params..).getBytes();

    response.setContentLength((int) b.length);
    OutputStream responseOutputStream = response.getOutputStream();
    responseOutputStream.write(b);
}
```

`getJNLP` is a method which returns the whole JNLP file as a `String`.

This seems to work fine. But am I missing anything. Are there any additional headers etc to be set?

UPDATE: The reason I am not using the JnlpDownloadServlet is because, I have to launch this JNLP from 2 different webapps - a Java one & a DOTNET one. I obviously cannot use JnlpDownloadServlet from the DOTNET webapp. I have written similar code (as above) in the DOTNET app to launch the JNLP. So I am just keeping it the same in the Java app also.

Comment: This question is to broad. It's not code review service. Do you have any errors?

Comment: The task is just to give the client a valid jnlp-File, so I think a static link to the generated jnlp-file should work, too.
Since you didn't add anything about the generation of the jnlp-File or the versions.xml its hard to say if you forgot anything.

Comment: @Turo The jnlp file is not static - it's generated at runtime by the `getJNLP` method.

Comment: Sorry, since getJNLP() has no parameters I thogth it would by fix by the moment the page is shown.

Comment: @Turo - sorry! I just showed it without params for simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is more to know.

For example: The Jnlp-Download-Service **performs substitutions** for the codebase and href, which is important if you install the same WebStart-application on different servers (dev, qa, prod). So this will work on all servers:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<jnlp spec='7.0' href='$$name' version='2.5-null' codebase='$$codebase'>
  <information>...
```

There are a lot more benefits you would loose when not using the JnlpDownloadServlet.

Please take a look at: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/downloadservletguide.html#substitutions

**But**, you could start a WebStart-Application without any Servlet, i.e. without JnlpDownloadServlet. You could even start a WebStart-Application without any server involved. If you put the jnlp-file and all the resources onto a windows directory, then you do not need any application-server.

For example: I have two files under c:\tmp\webstartdemo

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="file:///C:/tmp/webstartdemo">
    <resources>
        <j2se version="1.7+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
        <jar href="SwingGui.jar" main="true" />
    </resources>
    <application-desc name="Demo" main-class="Demo"/>
</jnlp>
```

Plus a mini *SwingGui.jar* with just one class:

```
public class Demo {
  public static void main(String... args){
      javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello World");
   }
}
```

Then I start it with:

```
javaws c:\tmp\webstartdemo\demo.jnlp
```

Of course you could place your jnlp-file and all the resources in a webserver, but it does not need to be dynamic. I hope that this is the answer to your question.

Comment: The JnlpDownloadServlet can't be used to generate a JNLP in all cases e.g. it doesn't support substitution of launch specific <argument>s. In this case, a second servlet can be used to generate the JNLP and the JnlpDownloadSerlvet used to handle the jars etc

Comment: I don't have any substitutions. So does it make a difference if I use JnlpDownloadServlet or not?

Comment: I have updated the question with the reason why I am not using JnlpDownloadServlet

Comment: But I want to launch it from the webapplication - i.e. the JNLP is not static - it gets generated at runtime from the server based on the requirement. My question was based on that. If I am launching it from the server without using JnlpDownloadServlet - is what I am doing enough or do I need to do anything extra?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this will be enough.

You do not get all the other features like *substituion*, *versioning* or *compressing*, but **it will work**. As I said, there is no need for any extra service to start a WebStart-Application.